# Consulta sql entre 2 tablas

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo la tabla persona:

```
id nombre sexo
 1   paco  1
 2   elena 2
 3   alien null
```

Tengo la tabla sexo:

```
 id  genero 
 1   hombre  
 2   mujer
```

Partiendo de la bas q es una BBDD del cliente que no puedo tocar, hago la siguiente consulta:

```
select p.nombre as name, g.genero as gender from persona p, sexo g 
where p.nombre = 'paco' and g.id = p.sexo ;   => esto funciona sin problemas
```

DUDA:

```
select p.nombre as name, g.genero as gender from persona p, sexo g 
where p.nombre = 'alien' and g.id = p.sexo ;
```

=> esto NO FUNCIONA, supongo que será por el null que tiene pero como puedo 
    hacer para obtener resultado?

Comment: es mas admitible lo que dice Pablo :3, lo que creía era que servía pero no arrojaria un resultado debido a su valor null :)

Comment: Sí que puede ser un resultado lógico. Si ese dato no es obligatorio no tienes por qué ignorar ese registro.

Comment: Pensé que era así , ademas creo que lo explique mal :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No has explicado en qué sentido una consulta funciona y la otra no. Lo cierto es que, como Pablo explicó, ninguna de las 2 consultas funcionará correctamente debido a que no has definido correctamente las condiciones del join.

Lo mejor para evitar este tipo de problemas es usar la notación más estándar para los joins para evitar este tipo de olvidos:

```
select p.nombre as name, 
       g.genero as gender
  from persona p
  join sexo g
    on g.id = p.sexo
where p.nombre = 'alien'
```

Luego, cambiar esto para manejar el `null` se vuelve trivial, ya que solo necesitas cambiar el `join` por un `left join`:

```
select p.nombre as name, 
       g.genero as gender
  from persona p
  left join sexo g
    on g.id = p.sexo
where p.nombre = 'alien'
```

Es mejor evitar la notación del `(+)` para los left joins de ser posible, ya que es una sintaxis vieja y abandonada que Oracle mismo no recomienda usar.

Comment: gracias, es perfecto

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, en tu consulta no estás relacionando las dos tablas, debería ser:

```
select p.nombre as name, g.genero as gender from persona p, sexo g 
where g.id = p.sexo and p.nombre = 'alien';
```

Segundo, para que te devuelva resultados aun no existiendo valores en la tabla sexo para un `id=null` tienes que usar el operador (+):

```
select p.nombre as name, g.genero as gender from persona p, sexo g 
where g.id(+) = p.sexo and p.nombre = 'alien';
```

Como ves, el operador se coloca en la condición que relaciona las dos tablas, concretamente en el lado de la tabla en que puede no existir un valor concreto (null en este caso).

Comment: gracias, al final use la solución de sstan

Comment: Perfecto, es la mejor de las presentadas.